# Display only particular toggle on multiple cards when clicked in VUEJS

Tags: html, vuejs2

I am working on this feature where i have multiple cards with a toggle inside it.

I am getting the values for the card from the api, and using the
When i am trying to click on the toggle, the toggle on the cards opens where by i want to display the particular card toggle.

Here is the code for it:

```
<div v-for="values in api" :key="values.id">
<card>
   <li>
     <b-link v-b-toggle.collapse>
      {{ value.name }}
      </b-link>
      <b-collapse id="collapse">
      <pre>
         {{ value.address }}
      </pre>
      </b-collapse>
   </li>
</card>
<div>
```

Please assist

Comment: The 2 b-collapse elements have same id which may cause issue. They both will toggle with same click. Each element must have unique id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the same id attribute of the collapse. You need to change the id assignment. Try the code below:

```
<div v-for="values in api" :key="values.id">
 <card>
   <li>
     <b-link v-b-toggle="`collapse-${values.id}`">
      {{ value.name }}
      </b-link>
      <b-collapse :id="`collapse-${values.id}`">
      <pre>
         {{ value.address }}
      </pre>
      </b-collapse>
   </li>
 </card>
<div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind response @beshambher. i used a v-bind and it worked

Comment: Then try this v-bind:id="'collapse-'+values.id"

Comment: Or simply :id="values.id"

Comment: @ Beshambher Chaukhwan  i cannot toggle it

Comment: Its the same code as mentioned above @Beshambher chaukhwan

Comment: Did u try v-bind:id="'collapse-'+values.id" and :id="values.id" ??

Comment: Oh wait I think I got the issue. Give me a moment.

Comment: @Pheonix please check the answer now. I updated it again to take the collapse id as value. For more information please refer the `Using Value` part of `Usage` in bootstrap vue collapse documentation in here https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse

Comment: Yup, i just tried, working perfect. many thanks  @Beshambher chaukhwan